# Manual bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

I need to create a manual bibliography, in order to follow very precise layout guidelines.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{111}
\raggedright

\bibitem{} Anscombe, E. 1981/1971. ``Causality and Determination,'' in 
  \emph{Metaphysics and the Philosophy of Mind: Collected Philosophical Papers of 
    G.E.M. Anscombe}. Minneapolis: University of Minnesota Press. 133--47. 

\end{thebibliography}
```

However, this gives me square brackets with itemized numbers for each entry. I don't want this. I want flush left for first line, not itemization, and hanging lines indented, like a regular academic bibliography. That is what I'm required to do, at any rate.

Advice?

Answer (score 16):

Not entirely sure whether this is what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{}%
           {\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\parindent}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{-\parindent}%
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{111}
\raggedright
\bibitem{abc} Anscombe, E. 1981/1971. ``Causality and Determination,'' in \emph{Metaphysics and the Philosophy of Mind: Collected Philosophical Papers of G.E.M.\ Anscombe}. Minneapolis: University of Minnesota Press. 133--47.
\bibitem{def} Anscombe, E. 1981/1971. ``Causality and Determination,'' in \emph{Metaphysics and the Philosophy of Mind: Collected Philosophical Papers of G.E.M.\ Anscombe}. Minneapolis: University of Minnesota Press. 133--47.
\bibitem{ghi} Anscombe, E. 1981/1971. ``Causality and Determination,'' in \emph{Metaphysics and the Philosophy of Mind: Collected Philosophical Papers of G.E.M.\ Anscombe}. Minneapolis: University of Minnesota Press. 133--47.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The entire definition of `thebibliography` was copied from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) and updated with the appropriate length items. Additionally, the label has been removed.

Comment: @user25465 The best way to say thanks is to accept the answer and upvote it. If you expect to be back to SE often, pick a username that identifies you a little more personally.